# Trying to set text in a colum based on a match on a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a inventory control workbook and I am looking to have a column with the words "Order Placed" once I have clicked on the button to place order. I want to make sure that it is based on the right criteria. Currently in I am using a formula to place that text but once I clear the order form that goes away because its using an index match function within an if statement.

This is my current Order Placed Sub

```
Sub orderPlaced()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim startCell As range, lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = Sheets("Re-Order List")
    
        
        'This part Copies the requested information
        Sheets("Re-Order List").Select
        range("A1").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        'This part Pastes the requested information in the history
        Sheets("Order History").Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
        range("A65536").Select
        Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllExceptBorders, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        'This part Copies the requested information
        Sheets("Re-Order List").Select
        Set startCell = range("A3")
        lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, startCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        lastCol = ws.Cells(startCell.Row, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        ws.range(startCell, ws.Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        'This part Pastes the requested information in the history
        Sheets("Order History").Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
        range("A65536").Select
        Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        'This part adds orderplaced below order form
        Sheets("Order History").Select
        range("A65536").Select
        Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Select
        With Selection
        .Value = "Order Placed :"
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        End With
        'This part adds the date
        Sheets("Order History").Select
        range("B65536").Select
        Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Select
        With Selection
        .Value = Date
        .NumberFormat = "dd/mmm/yyyy"
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        End With
        'this will set the comment in inventory to ordered
        
        '*************************
        
        'NEEDED CODE WILL GO HERE
        
        '*************************
        
        Sheets("Inventory").Select
        range("K6:K400").ClearContents
        
        'This part Clears the order form
        Sheets("Re-Order List").Select
        range("A4:D5000").ClearContents
     
        
    
       
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
   
    
End Sub
```

This is my Add to Order Sub

```
Sub add2Order()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim C As range, rng As range, D As range, Rng1 As range, mnrng As range, acrng As range

Sheets("Inventory").Select
Set rng = range("K6:K400")

    For Each C In rng
    
        If InStr(1, C, "X") > 0 Then
            'first select material number and name
            Set mnrng = range(C.Offset(0, -9), C.Offset(0, -8))
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            mnrng.Copy
            'paste in reorder sheet
            Sheets("Re-Order List").Select
            Selection.End(xlDown).Select
            range("A400").Select
            Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
            Application.CutCopyMode = True
        End If
    Next
Sheets("Inventory").Select
Set Rng1 = range("K6:K400")

    For Each D In Rng1
    
        If InStr(1, D, "X") > 0 Then
    
            'Second select amount and cost
            Set acrng = range(D.Offset(0, -2), D.Offset(0, -1))
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            acrng.Copy
            'paste in reorder sheet
            Sheets("Re-Order List").Select
            Selection.End(xlDown).Select
            range("C400").Select
            Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
            Application.CutCopyMode = True
        End If
    Next

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Code that is close is as follows

```
Sub test()
'
Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
Dim C As range, a As range
Set w1 = Sheets("Inventory")
Set w2 = Sheets("Re-Order List")
With w1
  For Each C In .range("$A$6:$A$400")
    Set a = w2.Columns(1).Find(C.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not a Is Nothing Then
      If IsEmpty(.Cells(C.Row, 1)) And .Cells(C.Row, 1).Value = w2.Cells(a.Row, 1) Then
        w1.Cells(C.Row, 12).Value = "Order Placed"
      End If
    End If
  Next C
End With
End Sub
```

This is the last piece to this puzzle to get it how I want it to work, I know for sure I will only have less than 400 materials to manage and if that grows I can update then but any help would be fantastic.

[This is the drive link for the actual sheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1reACU8gHkgHlMghXfG8cuQjer_GvU9i9/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please point exactly in your code what is not working as expected or raising an error?

Comment: @RicardoDiaz Its not that its causing an error, I need to dynamically place text in a cell based on if an item is on the order form. Right now I am doing this with the formula =IFERROR(IF(INDEX(Table2[Material Number],MATCH(C6,Table2[Name],0)) = [@[Material Number]],"Order Placed",""),"") but once I clear the order and place it in the order history form I lose that text because the material is no longer in the order form. So I want to be able to place it using code so that I can clear the form but still show that the materials were ordered.

Comment: Where in the code do you want it to happen?

Comment: Where is says 
        '*************************
        
        'NEEDED CODE WILL GO HERE
        
        '*************************

Comment: I'm sorry, I found the cells with that formula but it's not clear for me where do you want to copy the values

Comment: You can [edit] your question and add a screenshot showing the before and after. That would make thinks easier.

Comment: So essentially, all that I am looking for is when I run the order placed macro... If the Material number is on the order form(sheet 2) then find that material number on sheet 1 and place the text "order placed" in column L of sheet 1

Comment: This is a little off-topic, but its better to avoid doing so much Selecting and just directly reference the ranges you want to interact with. Instead of Range.Select and Selection.copy you should just do Range.Copy. And if you need to reference a different sheet, you can just say Sheet("Name").Range. Selecting is slow, and makes the screen jitter around a lot during execution. Plus it makes reading and writing the code more difficult, since you have to keep track of the currently active object instead of just reading the reference as written.

Comment: @EricScalise without knowing in what cells should be that placed, it's kind of difficult to assist you

Comment: good. let me know it and I'll try to give you a hand

Comment: @RicardoDiaz Thanks for what you did so far. I know its kind of hard to explain, I implemented the code without  the selections and that is working. I can try to type some pseudo code to help explain what I am looking for...

Pseudo Code:
`code`
If reorderListSheet.range("A4:A400").Value is equal to inventorySheet.Range(A6:A400).Value Then

inventorySheet.Range(that matched above statement).offset(0, 10). value = "order placed"

end if
`code`
does that make sense

Comment: That's why I have the If statement with the Index(Match) in it because it does what I need until I clear the form on the reorder list Sheet.... trying to do this without the formula altogether since it doesn't stay as order placed once I run the Sub orderPlaced()

Comment: @RicardoDiaz I worked on this last night and got close to what I want but this places the Order Placed Text in every cell regardless of match.
`Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
Dim C As range, a As range
Set w1 = Sheets("Inventory")
Set w2 = Sheets("Re-Order List")
With w1
  For Each C In .range("$A$6:$A$400")
    Set a = w2.Columns(1).Find(C.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not a Is Nothing Then
      If IsEmpty(.Cells(C.Row, 1)) And .Cells(C.Row, 1).Value = w2.Cells(a.Row, 1) Then
        w1.Cells(C.Row, 12).Value = "Order Placed"
      End If
    End If
  Next C
End With`

Comment: Please  [edit] tour question and add the relevant code

Comment: @RicardoDiaz I edited it to show the code that I have that is close

Comment: I’ll try to take a look at it this wknd

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer until you tell us exactly where do you want to place the information

I refactored your code so you don't use select and added some pseudo code that may give you a hint

```
Public Sub orderPlaced()

    ' Turn off stuff to speed up process
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'This part Copies the requested information
    Dim reorderListSheet As Worksheet
    Set reorderListSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Re-Order List")
    reorderListSheet.Range("A1").Copy
    
    'This part Pastes the requested information in the history
    Dim orderHistorySheet As Worksheet
    Set orderHistorySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Order History")
    orderHistorySheet.Cells(orderHistorySheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllExceptBorders, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    
    ' Find last row in reorder sheet
    Dim reorderLastRow As Long
    reorderLastRow = reorderListSheet.Cells(reorderListSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Find last column in reorder sheet
    Dim reorderLastColumn As Long
    reorderLastColumn = reorderListSheet.Cells(3, reorderListSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    'This part Copies the requested information
    Dim reorderStartCell As Range
    Set reorderStartCell = reorderListSheet.Range("A3")
    reorderListSheet.Range(reorderStartCell, reorderListSheet.Cells(reorderLastRow, reorderLastColumn)).Copy
    
    'This part Pastes the requested information in the history
    Dim orderHistoryLastRow As Long
    orderHistoryLastRow = orderHistorySheet.Cells(orderHistorySheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    orderHistorySheet.Range("A" & orderHistoryLastRow).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    
    'This part adds orderplaced below order form
    With orderHistorySheet.Range("A" & orderHistoryLastRow).Offset(3, 0)
        .Value = "Order Placed :"
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    End With
    
    'This part adds the date
    With orderHistorySheet.Range("B" & orderHistoryLastRow).Offset(3, 0)
        .Value = Date
        .NumberFormat = "dd/mmm/yyyy"
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    End With
    
    'this will set the comment in inventory to ordered
    
    '*************************
    
    ' THIS NEXT IS PSEUDO CODE BECAUSE I COULDN'T UNDERSTAND YOUR REQUIREMENT
    Dim targetCell As Range
    Set targetCell = orderHistorySheet.Range("A1").Value = "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(Table2[Material Number],MATCH(C6,Table2[Name],0)) = [@[Material Number]],""Order Placed"",""""),"""")"
    
    ' turn that into a value
    targetCell.Value = targetCell.Value
    
    '*************************
    
    ' Clear inventory sheet
    Dim inventorySheet As Worksheet
    Set inventorySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Inventory")
    inventorySheet.Range("K6:K400").ClearContents
    
    'This part Clears the order form
    reorderListSheet.Range("A4:D5000").ClearContents
    
    
    ' Turn on stuff again
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
   
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I FIGURED IT OUT!!!!!!!!

```
'this will set the comment in inventory to ordered
    
    '*************************
    Dim r1 As range
    Dim r2 As range
    Dim cell As range
    
    Set r1 = Sheets("Inventory").range("B6:B400")
    Set r2 = Sheets("Re-Order List").range("A4:A400")

    For Each cell In r1
        If IsError(Application.Match(cell, r2, 0)) Then
            cell.Offset(, 12) = ""
        Else
            cell.Offset(, 12) = "Order Placed"
            ' If found I need the value from Sheet2 that is in Col B of the matching row.
        End If
    Next cell
    '*************************
```